# Reading double numbers from mixed file

Tags: java, file-io

Trying to read double numbers only where the file contains numbers and words. Code i have done so far reads from file properly and prints full list with numbers and words. Not sure how to exclude words and print read only double numbers.

```
 public void doubleFromFile()
 {
              Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

     Scanner fileScan;
     boolean validName = false;
    double num = 0.0;

     do
     {

         System.out.print("Enter file name: ");
         String str = scan.nextLine();

        try 
        {

            fileScan = new Scanner(new File(str));
            validName = true;

        while(fileScan.hasNextLine())
        {

            try
            {

            str = fileScan.nextLine();
            num = Double.parseDouble(str);

      System.out.println(str);
            }
             catch (NumberFormatException nfe) 
             {
                System.out.println("is not a Double number");
             }   


        }//end while

        }// end try



         catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe)
           {
              System.out.println("Invalid File name: enter again");
           }

     }while(!validName);

  }//end doubleFromFile method
```

Comment: To read double numbers only from file that has words and numbers

Comment: No, that's what you want, what have you tried to do?

Comment: open file using do/while loop. Then with try/catch catching the exception for reading proper file name and double numbers only. Where the while loop when i put num = Double.parseDouble(str); it prints exception but not dobule numbers

Comment: @Nic.. Move your `try-catch` for `NumberFormatException` inside the while loop. Just surround `Double.parseDouble()` line with it.

Comment: @nic Can you update your sample code to show your parseDouble call? Right now your code reads each line in as a string and then prints it and nothing else.

Comment: Okay this is working now. Though inside catch for number format exception the system print line sill prints the message.

Comment: try changing your try like this: `  try
            {
            num = Double.parseDouble(str);
            }
             catch (NumberFormatException nfe) 
             {
                System.out.println("is not a Double number");
             }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working test

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner("aaaa 1.1 bbb\n3");
    sc.useLocale(Locale.US);
    while (sc.hasNext()) {
        if (sc.hasNextDouble()) {
            System.out.println(sc.nextDouble());
        } else {
            sc.next();
        }
    }
```

Note that I used US locale so that Scanner interpets "." as decimal separator, in my locale (default) it is ",". Also note that both 1.1 and 3 (integer) are recognized by nextDouble