# Read float numbers from file

Tags: java

How to read float numbers from file?

```
  0.00000E+00  2.12863E-01
  1.00000E-02  2.16248E-01
  2.00000E-02  2.19634E-01
```

in the file 2 spaces before the first column of numbers and between numbers. I have errors instantly:

```
s = new Scanner(new File("P0"));
while (s.hasNext()) {
    float x = s.nextFloat();
    float y = s.nextFloat();

    System.out.println("x = " + x + ", y = " + y);
}
```

Comment: How are you doing it now?

Comment: @mdl i added code below

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: God forbid I suggest using `while (s.hasNextFloat())`. I got burned at the stake last time I did that.

Comment: `number1` is not a float.... Did you mean that the file will be of the form `1.23456  1.23456\n1.23456  3.14159\netc`?

Comment: @Quincunx yes, i mean this, i wrote "number1" as an example

Comment: @Denis Your code works fine for me. What errors are you getting and what do your numbers look like?

Comment: @John u are right! Errors disappeared

Comment: That's interesting, isn't it @TedHopp?

Comment: @mdl i get errors as:Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.util.InputMismatchException
 at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:909)
 at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1530)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextFloat(Scanner.java:2388)
 at test.Test.getFilesCount(Test.java:17)
 at test.Test$1.run(Test.java:39)
 at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
 at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:733)

Comment: @Denis `InputMismatchException` means something in your input file P0 cannot be parsed as a `float`. Please make sure your input contains all numbers and exactly 2 numbers on each line. If you need to see what is being parsed in each interation, try `System.out.println(s.next());` in your while loop.

Comment: @mdl program didn't enter in "while", why? **s.hasNextFloat() = false**

Comment: @Denis your input file doesn't have numbers. It is trying to parse something that is not a number into a number, and failing.

Comment: @mdl i have problems with file:   0.00000E+00  2.12863E-01
  1.00000E-02  2.16248E-01
  2.00000E-02  2.19634E-01

Comment: Terminology please. What you have is either (1) *real numbers,* in ASCII, represented in *scientific notation,* and you want to *convert* them to floats, or (2) real binary float values, in which case you should be using DataInputStream.readFloat().

Comment: @Denis Copying & pasting your code and inputs gives me the expected result with no errors. I suppose you have something else going on, like reading from the wrong file or having an extra non-numeric value in your input file.

Comment: @mdl oh, really? strange. can u send me somehow your project? somewhere maybe stupid mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I understand my mistake. I need to use

```
s.useLocale(Locale.US);
```

because that Scanner interpets "." as decimal separator, in my locale (default) it is ",". Also note that both 1.1 and 3 (integer) are recognized by nextDouble

//according to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13613173/reading-double-numbers-from-mixed-file?rq=1)

Answer (score 3):

1. Read file line by line.
2. Split each line into words based on spaces.
3. Convert each word into float.

Here is the code:

```
    BufferedReader reader = null;

    try {
        // use buffered reader to read line by line
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(new File(
                "<FULL_FILE_PATH>"))));

        float x, y;
        String line = null;
        String[] numbers = null;
        // read line by line till end of file
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            // split each line based on regular expression having
            // "any digit followed by one or more spaces".

            numbers = line.split("\\d\\s+");

            x = Float.valueOf(numbers[0].trim());
            y = Float.valueOf(numbers[1].trim());

            System.out.println("x:" + x + " y:" + y);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Exception:" + e.toString());
    } finally {
        if (reader != null) {
            try {
                reader.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.err.println("Exception:" + e.toString());
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It really works, thanks! But it is 2 values in each line, and I want to appropriate them to variables x and y. How it is necessary to correct this part of a code?

Comment: Each line is split into three words in your case. First one is empty string and others are actual numbers. Use index 1 and 2 to get the numbers.

Comment: where i should use these index? Can u help me with this small part of code?

Comment: I have updated the code as per your requirement along with exception handling.