# Android -- Read float from .txt file

Tags: android, file, io, floating-point

I want to read millions of float values from a .txt file, but for now I am starting off by just trying to read one from a "test.txt" file, which contains 1.2345. I have placed this in the assets directory of my Android project.

I then try to read the float value like this:

```
   @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   // setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setContentView(new MyView(this));

    readFloatFromFile();
}


public void readFloatFromFile() {

     try{
          InputStream is = getAssets().open("Test.txt");

          DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(is);

          float f = din.readFloat();

          Log.d("FLOAT VALUE", Float.toString(f));


        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException fe)
        {
            System.out.println("FileNotFoundException : " + fe);
        }
        catch(IOException ioe)
        {
            System.out.println("IOException : " + ioe);
        }
    }
```

But what the log prints out is `D/FLOAT VALUE: 6.337074E-10`

I have been looking for a while online, but I haven't found another way that works so far. And also if I try to open the file from some path on my SD card, i get file not found and permission denied. Is this because I'm running Android 6.0 which needs me to grant permissions at runtime?

Comment: One more thing. If I am to read millions of float values, would it be more sensible to try and read from a .bin file, in order to not slow the device up too much?

Comment: `DataInputStream` is not for text files, but for files created using `DataOutputStream`.

Comment: Should I use FileInputStream instead?

Comment: You can't, as an asset is not a file. The [up-voted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21919582/115145) on the question that I marked as a duplicate shows using a `BufferedReader` wrapped around an `InputStreamReader`, and you can pass the `InputStream` from `open()` on `AssetManager` to the `InputStreamReader`. Note, though, that reading "millions of float values" may well crash your app with an `OutOfMemoryError`.

Comment: Wow yes finally works. I've spent an unreasonable amount of time on this. Thank you very much! About what you said of the millions of float values causing a crash, what would you say is the upper limit of the amount of values I can load from asset?

Comment: The source of the data (asset vs. something else) is not the issue. The heap limit may be as low as 16MB, though most likely you will be on a device with a heap limit of 32MB or higher. A million `float` values will be 4MB, and you still have the rest of your app to deal with. Usually, we avoid loading all that data into memory at once.

Answer (score 0):

when getting float value that cast into float like below code ..
for example :;

```
float l= (float) 6.123456;
Log.d("FLOAT VALUE", Float.toString(l));
```

you change this method in your code ..

```
float f =(float) din.readFloat();
```

Comment: @NileshRathod I don't quite understand. Doesn't readFloat return a float? Why would I need to add the cast?

Comment: because floating point value more there for if you can take double then no need to casting.